# Как определить скорость выполнения кода средствами Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, профилирование

Всё что нашёл, это Debug - Start Diagnostic Tool

Есть 2 функции. Их измеряю. Он выдаёт такие результаты.
Собственно, суть вопроса, верен ли способ, достаточен ли для обычных, не критичных к точности, проверок. И правильно ли я понимаю что затраченное время это четвёртый столбец (1.52 против 559.31).

Ну, и, быть может есть иной способ замерять скорость (без сторонних include'ов и т.д.).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

То, что Вы нашли - это профилирование. И это достаточно хороший способ искать узкие места и тормозящий код. Главное, уметь правильно трактовать и понимать результаты.

Там 4 основных столбца. Два первые показывают результаты текущего запуска в процентах, два последних - усредненное (я так понимаю в секундах, но давно я студии этого не делал).

Также они подписаны словами Inclusive (включительно) и Exclusive (исключая). Первое - это время выполнения кода, если бы замерять секундомером. А второе - это время выполнение функции, исключая вложенные вызовы. То есть, если внутри Вашей функции только вызов одной другой функции, то exclusive может быть почти нулевым.

Теперь к примеру с вопроса. Да, Ваш код в несколько сот раз быстрее (1.52 против 559.31). И это реальное время исполнение кода. Интересно то, что "функция с std" внутри себя вызывает что то очень тяжелое.